# Huggingeface model generator method do_sample parameter

Tags: huggingface-transformers

What does `do_sample` parameter of the [generate](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/model.html?highlight=do_sample#transformers.generation_utils.GenerationMixin.generate) method of the Hugging face model do?

> Generates sequences for models with a language modeling head. The method currently supports greedy decoding, multinomial sampling, beam-search decoding, and beam-search multinomial sampling.

```
do_sample (bool, optional, defaults to False) – Whether or not to use sampling; 
use greedy decoding otherwise.
```

When the Beam search length is 1, it can be called **greedy**. Does `do_sample=False` mean the same?

Answer (score 7):

If your `do_sample=True`, your `generate` method will use Sample Decoding. You can look at the different decoding strategies [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/decoding-strategies-that-you-need-to-know-for-response-generation-ba95ee0faadc). You can also play with the `temperature`  parameter.

Now, if `do_sample=False` and `num_beams=1`, then your `generate` method will use greedy decoding.

Comment: By Sample decoding do you mean Random Sampling ?